# How to use @OneToMany and @ManyToOne nest?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have three entities as below:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id", "bricksets", "themes"})
@Entity
public class Brand {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;                // Unique database primary key

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Brickset> bricksets;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Theme> themes;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id"})
@ToString(exclude={"brand", "theme"})
@Entity
public class Brickset {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;            // Unique database primary key

    @NotNull
    private String number;      // set number

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
    private Brand brand;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "theme_id")
    private Theme theme;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id"})
@ToString(exclude={"brand", "brickset"})
@Entity
public class Theme {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;                // Unique database primary key

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
    private Brand brand;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Theme", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Brickset> brickset;
}
```

But I met compile error as below, I tried to solve it by myself, but I am very new in JPA/Hibernate, can you help me and how can I do next? I thought the problem is what I used ManyToOne and OneToMany in Entity Theme, that might be confused by JPA/Hibernate, may I make sense?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.zangland.entity.Theme.brickset
```

Comment: you specified the type instead of the name of the target for the "mappedBy" attribute. It should be `theme` instead of `Theme` in the very last @OneToMany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Collection for a `@OneToMany` annotation.

Hibernate requires that persistent collection-valued fields be declared as an interface type.

The actual interface might be `java.util.Set`, `java.util.Collection`, `java.util.List`, `java.util.Map`, `java.util.SortedSet`, `java.util.SortedMap` or anything you like ("anything you like" means you will have to write an implementation of `org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType`.)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "theme", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Brickset> brickset;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, now error is Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.zangland.entity.Brickset.Theme in com.zangland.entity.Theme.brickset

Comment: @mikezang try it with lower case `theme`